# proxy in a docker container implemented only with iptables - refuses connection

Tags: docker, api-gateway

We need to implement a proxy only by using iptables in a container and all traffic from other containers use this container to reach internet. Additionally in this proxy, drop trafffic to yahoo.com domain and allow the rest.

I've a Oracle VM Box in windows that hosts a Ubuntu VM. In this VM, I've installed docker with 4 containers having Ubuntu image as shown here:

[image]

Requirement is any traffic from avant3, avant4 or avant2 should use avant1 as proxy to reach internet. avant1 should only implement iptables rules to become a tcp proxy.

In avant1 container in interactive mode, did the following as per [this  link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html):

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Going into avant3 and executing curl and specifying avant1 as proxy, getting this response:

```
root@340787f0b409:/# curl -x 172.19.0.3 "www.google.com" -I
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.19.0.3 port 1080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
root@340787f0b409:/# curl -x 172.19.0.3:80 "www.google.com" -I
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.19.0.3 port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
root@340787f0b409:/# 18.0
```

Can anybody guide me on the mistake I'm doing to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a proxy solution, I thought of a different approach, avant1 will act as the gateway to all containers in localnet & testnet bridge networks. Either while creating the bridge networks you can specify a custom gateway as 172.18.0.2 & 172.19.0.3 for localnet and testnet respectively or use ip route command to replace the default gateways in individual containers.

In my case, added a FORWARD drop rule for domain yahoo.com in avant1.
Entering into avant1 container interactively, did the following:

```
iptables --append FORWARD -d yahoo.com -j DROP
```

& launching avant3 container interactively, executed

```
ip route replace default via 172.19.0.3 dev eth0
```

then,

```
curl yahoo.com -I
```

will not allow the traffic anymore in avant3 while allowing rest to passthrough